# jQuery: code adds too much html to dom

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on a function where users can filter a list of events (shows in theatre and so on) by month, location and name.

[image]

Because they can select more than one filter, a list is shown below the dropdown menus containing the users selection.

My problem is, that no matter which element is clicked it is added to all three lists. If an option is unchecked, it is removed only from the first list (which is the one containing months).

See jQuery code:

```
        var options = [];

        var currentSelectionMonths = [];
        var currentSelectionLocations = [];
        var currentSelectionEvents = [];

        $('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function (event)
        {
            var $target = $(event.currentTarget),
                val = $target.attr('data-value'),
                $inp = $target.find('input'),
                idx;

            if ((idx = options.indexOf(val)) > -1)
            {
                options.splice(idx, 1);
                setTimeout(function () { $inp.prop('checked', false) }, 0);

                if (options.length === 0)
                {
                    $('.currentselection').hide();
                }

                if ($(this).parent('#months'))
                {
                    currentSelectionMonths.splice(idx, 1);  
                    $('.timelist').html(currentSelectionMonths);
                }

                if ($(this).parent('#locations'))
                {
                    currentSelectionMonths.splice(idx, 1);
                    $('.locationlist').html(currentSelectionLocations);
                }

                if ($(this).parent('#events'))
                {
                    currentSelectionMonths.splice(idx, 1);
                    $('.eventlist').html(currentSelectionEvents);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                options.push(val);
                setTimeout(function () { $inp.prop('checked', true) }, 0);

                $('.currentselection').show();

                if ($(this).parent('#months'))
                {
                    currentSelectionMonths.push($(this).attr('data-value') + ' ');
                    $('.timelist').html(currentSelectionMonths);
                }

                if ($(this).parent('#locations'))
                {
                    currentSelectionLocations.push($(this).attr('data-value') + ' ');
                    $('.locationlist').html(currentSelectionLocations);
                }

                if ($(this).parent('#events'))
                {
                    currentSelectionEvents.push($(this).attr('data-value') + ' ');
                    $('.eventlist').html(currentSelectionEvents);
                }
            }

            $(event.target).blur();

            console.log(options);
            return false;
        });
```

And the corresponding html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: greenyellow;">
            <div class="dropdowns" style="display: inline;">
                <div class="dropdown" style="display: inline;">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Zeitraum
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="months">
                        @foreach (var month in Model.MonthsList)
                        {
                            <li><a href="#" data-value="@month" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" class="timeboxes" />&nbsp;@month</a></li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown" style="display: inline;">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Spielstätte
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="locations">
                        @foreach (var location in Model.LocationList)
                        {
                            <li><a href="#" data-value="@location" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" class="locationboxes" />&nbsp;@location</a></li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown" style="display: inline;">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Produktion
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="events">
                        @foreach (var evnt in Model.EventsList)
                        {
                            <li><a href="#" data-value="@evnt" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" class="eventboxes" />&nbsp;@evnt</a></li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="container-fluid currentselection" style="display: none;">
        <div class="headline">
            <h3>Aktuelle Auswahl:</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <p>Zeitraum: </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <span class="timelist"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <p>Spielstätte: </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <span class="locationlist"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <p>Produktion: </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <span class="eventlist"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried nesting the if-statements with else-statements: no change.
I tried selecting the li-elements instead of a: no change.
I tried searching for children instead of parents: no change.

There clearly is something I´m not seeing, please help :)

**Edit:**
Don´t worry about the greenyellow background, it´s for testing purposes only :D

**Edit2:**
As I found out (and schellmax did, too) `parent(...)` must be changed to `parents(...)`. The reason why deleting items did not work was that programmers get blind after spending too much time on finding a solution:
I tried to delete only from one list, three times `currentSelectionMonths.splice(idx, 1);`

Comment: As I just found out, .parent does not work. It should be .parents(...).length. This leads to expected behavior, but deleting items does not work yet (only sometimes...)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(this).parents('#months'))
```

should be

```
if ($(this).parents('#months').length)
```

`parent()` (as most jquery functions) always returns a jquery object, which always evaluates to true, so you have to check the length attribute, which is '0' in case of no result, evaluating to false.

Comment: Have you considered whether or not this should be a comment?

Comment: It's actually a solution to the problem given, so I thought an 'answer' would be fine?

Comment: This does not work. The statement evaluates to false.

Comment: Looking closer, i found another problem: parent() will only find the direct parent of an element, but your  'a' is nested in an 'li' element first, then comes the 'ul#months'. So you need to use the 'parents()' (with an s) function to traverse up the dom tree, updated my example code. Note you have to do this for all similar checks in your code ('#locations, #events').

Comment: Yepp, I found out myself and commented my question a few minutes ago. Adding items works perfectly, deleting them works only for the month-list. Items are deleted from the options-list, but not from the others.